# Graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to use [pyreverse](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/6883) to generate images of UML diagrams for a project source code. When I run the pyreverse command and specify to generate .png images, it runs, and then, after a while, it shows:

```
dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.271394 to fit
dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.333083 to fit
```

Then, if I open either image, the text is unreadable because it got scaled. Is there a way to just not scale, and let the image be large size?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz. Seems, `pyreverse` is using `graphviz` backend for drawing graphs (dot is language and utility of graphviz).

Comment: I see that link you gave, but I'm not sure how I can use it to fix this. Can you explain more please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have `pyreverse` on my distro, but the idea is that first you generate your output graph with `pyreverse -o` in `.dot` format with `-o` option and then manually invoke `sfdp` on it as described e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417411/laying-out-a-large-graph-with-graphviz.

Comment: That worked, but the classes are scattered all around in a circle. Is it possible to make them in a hierarchical view? (like on top of each other)

Comment: Can you give input data and the codes tried. So that we will be in a better position to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a different layout program by specifying the `-p` option. By default, **pyreverse** uses the dot program from the **Graphviz** package, but other options, such as **neato** or **fdp** may produce diagrams with different layouts and scaling.

Also, you can try using the `-o` option to specify the output format of the image. For example, using `-o svg` will generate an SVG image, which can be scaled without losing quality.